# Window Phone in-app webBrowser with displaying j-Query+ajax website

Tags: windows-phone-7, jquery

I am new to Window Phone, and I am developing a in-app webview application. The website which i used for Window Phone is using javascript+jquery+ajax jsp.

some of the link in that webpage using Window Phone webbrowser cannot get the click event, so the page cannot negative to another page inside webbrowser component.

But while i am using the Browser on Window Phone (IE) , seems it work fine on negativing.

Can anyone help me on this issue?

Is that i need to enable some function in in-app webbrowser component?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the [`IsScriptEnabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.isscriptenabled%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) property is set to true:

> **WebBrowser.IsScriptEnabled Property**
>   Enables or disables scripting.
>   *This applies to the next document that is navigated to, not the
>   current document*. This property is false by default. Set this property
>   to true to enable scripting, or false to disable scripting.

Comment: Thanks Olivier, I have already added this parameter and set it as true. Some of the link in the browser work fine but some can't.... The link in bottom layer is able to click and navigate but those link gen in body can't....